# How to call a function just by entering the screen in Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

it should be like:

if entered this screen:
     call(function)
I am also writing code using .kv file and .py at the same time so please give me a tip that will work in my occasion)

Answer (score 3):

Use either `on_pre_enter` or `on_enter` events in Python code or in kv file. Please refer the following snippets or another example using [on_pre_enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541494/how-to-update-stringproperty-variable-in-kivy/51543562#51543562)

[ScreenManager Events](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen)

> **Events:**
>
> ```
> on_pre_enter: ()
> ```
>
> Event fired when the screen is about to be used: the entering
>   animation is started.

## Python Code

```
class ScreenTwo(Screen):

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.callback()

    def callback(self):
        print("callback")
```

## kv file

```
<ScreenTwo>:
    on_pre_enter: root.callback()
```